# Getting row which have latest time mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get a row which have latest created time, 
Example, i have table with `news_id, news_content, news_postedon`. This table have 10 rows of data,

Now i want to pull row which have latest time of `new_postedon`,

I am using codeigniter,

I added below code,

```
function view_latestnews()
{
    $this->db->join('sc_users', 'sc_users.user_id = sc_news.news_postedby');
    $this->db->select_max('news_postedon');
    return $this->db->get('sc_news')->row();
}
```

By using this function i got only value of news_posted on which is max like `(stdClass Object ( [news_postedon] => 2015-04-12 21:28:21 ))`,
But i could not get value of news_content

How can i get complete row which have latest time of posted using codeigniter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your table schema along with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function view_latestnews()
{
   $this->db->join('sc_users', 'sc_users.user_id = sc_news.news_postedby');
   $this->db->where('news_postedon = (SELECT max(news_postedon) FROM  sc_news)');
   return $this->db->get('sc_news')->row();
}
```